# Replace trailing characters with another character

Tags: python

I have strings which end in a number of 8s. Example: GEWTIMRZGYYTANJYG4888888.

I want to replace these 8s with equal signs, but the number of 8s at the end isn't always consistent, and there may be other 8s in the string. I've tried rstrip and replace, but I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Use rstrip and then compare the length of the string before and after to find how many 8s were removed. Then add that many equals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution without regex

```
data = "GEWTIMRZGYYTANJYG4888888"
stripped = data.rstrip("8")
new_data = stripped + "=" * (len(data) - len(stripped))
```